# Base change of integral scheme of finite type over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an integral scheme of finite type over a field $k$. If $k'\supseteq k$ is a field extension, then $X' = X\otimes_k k'$ is not necessarily integral.

> Why does each irreducible component of $X'$ have the same dimension of $X$?

Comment: After a finite field extension, the irreducible components of the base change become geometrically irreducible, precisely, after base change to the algebraic closure $\kappa$ of $k$ in the function field $k(X)$.  Thus, assume that $k'/k$ is finite.  Then $X'\to X$ is finite and faithfully flat.  So now you can apply the Going Up and Going Down Theorems (Cohen-Seidenberg).

Comment: I don't get your reduction step: why can I suppose that $k'/k$ is finite? By 'algebraic closure' you mean 'integral closure'?

Comment: For a field extension $k\to K$, e.g., for $K=k(X)$, the *algebraic closure* of $k$ in $K$ is the set of all elements of $K$ that satisfy a nontrivial polynomial equation over $k$.  This is a subextension $\kappa$ of $K/k$, and it is finite over $k$ if $K/k$ is finitely generated (often proved via Noether normalization). Every irreducible component $Y$ of $X\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} \text{Spec}\ \kappa$ has pure dimension equal to $\text{dim}(X)$ (Cohen-Seidenberg). As $\kappa$ is algebraically closed in $\kappa(Y)$, $Y$ is a geometrically irreducible $\kappa$-scheme of dimension $\text{dim}(X)$.

Comment: If you are willing to assume that $\kappa/k$ is Galois, then this is quite easy to visualise. The Galois group of this extension acts transitively on the irreducible components over the algebraic closure, from which it follows that they all have the same dimension.

Comment: The dimension of the local ring at a closed point of $X$ is constant (equal to the transcendence degree of $k(X)$ over $k$). This remains true after extension of the base field.